# Table name as PostgreSQL function parameter / ERROR: column ".." does not exist

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm new to pgsql. I just want to use a table name as a function parameter in pgsql.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION user_test_table_name_as_input (table_name text)
RETURNS VOID 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    i int;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN EXECUTE 'SELECT DISTINCT category FROM' || quote_ident(table_name)
    LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE '%', i;
    END LOOP;
END
$$
```

When I try to use this function...

```
SELECT user_test_table_name_as_input (table_name);
```

...i get this error:

```
ERROR: column "table_name" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
```

I read the related threads, like [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter), but the other proposed solutions (Concatenation, format() ), do not work for me, neither. Any idea?

Comment: Try 'table_name' as the argument to the call of your stored procedure. (With quotes as it's text)

Comment: Thank you. I realized that I just forgot the quotes when using the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'table_name' needs quotes as the argument to the call of your stored procedure - it's text.